# apt-get or package manager not installing packages when DSL broadband modem is used

Tags: linux, networking, router

When I say

`apt-get install` or `apt-get update` or use software manager in Backtrack, it does not connect to the repository server.

The following error is displayed:

```
0% [Connecting to 32.repository.backtrack-linux.org (ip-address)]
```

otherwise internet is working fine.

My modem is a TP-Link.

I am not able to install any package or upgrade it. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you ping the repository?

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a problem with your repository list. I experienced update problems with my Linux_Mint. I found this post and it worked:

http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=132837

CODE:

1. sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists /var/lib/apt/lists_backup
2. sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists
3. sudo apt-get update